# What on earth is a T-Spin

Tags: tetris

What on earth is a TSpin? Or a T-Spin Single? Or a T-Spin Double or Triple? I have never known but I keep getting them left right and centre. Please help me out!

Comment: http://tetris.wikia.com/wiki/T-Spin ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a [wiki](http://tetris.wikia.com/wiki/T-Spin)

> Some games give scoring rewards for twisting a tetromino into a tight space. When this is done with a T tetromino, it is called a T-spin.

Well, it's better to see it in motion to better understand what it really is.

Here is also a written [step-by-step guide](http://tetris.wikia.com/wiki/T-Spin_Guide)